# see rtp vp8 stream in vlc

Tags: gstreamer, vlc, rtp, vp8

I have an rtp stream that I can capture and see with gstreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)VP8, payload=(int)96"  port=10035 ! rtpvp8depay ! decodebin ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

I would like to build an sdp file for VLC app to see the same video. I tried this, but it doesn't do the job:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
m=video 10035 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:1000
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
```

Comment: Is the `m=video {{PORT}} RTP/AVP 96` line a typo?

Comment: @MikhailVasilyev no, it's a placeholder. It's actually 10035 as showed on the next line. By mistake, I copied here both template line and the resolved line. Removed it now, to resolve any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
m=video 10035 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:1000
a=rtpmap:**120** VP8/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
```

i think is ->  a=rtpmap:**96** VP8/90000

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't use that setup anymore, so cannot check your fix.